# Use Canvas as style of Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, wear-os

Hello,                                                                              At First I want to say sorry that my English is not the best.
In my Android Project, I have a Canvas Shaped View.
My Question is.
Is it possible to use the Canvas shaped View as style of a Button?

Comment: Yes. You can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349155/how-do-i-add-a-button-to-canvas-without-letting-the-button-resize

Comment: This links to an answer for java.awt.Button using FlowLayout as a solution. Both do not exist in Android, so the link is probably not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the view like a button by setting an OnClickListener on it. No need to use a dedicated Button object.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting this as an answer to your question.